# QueryString From Shared Function

Tags: vb.net, query-string

I'm trying to get a query string from a shared function in a code-behind model using VB.NET.  You have to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("Query")` in order to get it from a shared function, however doing `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Count` gives back 0, which obviously isn't right in my case as there's many that exist.  Is there some sort of issue with using this static call from a shared function?

Answer (score 0):

If `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Count` returns 0 this probably means that the parameters are not in the request string but rather being posted if there are any. Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.Count`?

Comment: But there's definitely multiple query strings specified, as the HTTP information tells me so ;)